# javascript checking if str equals foo or bar

Tags: javascript

I am trying to work out if a string equals 'foo' or 'bar', from by tests below it looks like test4 is the best way to achieve this but I would have thought that test3 is the best method, but this returns false.

Why does this return false and is there a better approach that test4?

```js
var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
var str = 'f';
var test;
test = str == arr[0] ? true:false;
console.log('test1',test);
console.log('returns false');

test = str == 'f' ? true:false;
console.log('test2',test);
console.log('returns true');

test = str == (arr[0] || 'f') ? true:false;
console.log('test3',test);
console.log('returns false');


test = str == (arr[0] && 'f') ? true:false;
console.log('test4',test);
console.log('returns true');

test = (str == arr[0]) || (str == 'f') ? true:false;
console.log('test5',test);
console.log('returns true');
```

Comment: You need to define your criteria for "best". Test 3 and 4 do very different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `||` operator does not let you write an expression as in your third test that does what the test expects. It's syntactically correct but semantically different from what you intend to do.

The last test can be written simply:

```
test = (str == arr[0]) || (str == 'f');
```

There's no need for the `? :` operator; the result of the above expression will already be either `true` or `false`, because both sides of the `||` return boolean values.

To explain further,

```
test = str == (arr[0] || 'f');
```

will first evaluate the `||` expression. It will evaluate `arr[0]`, and if the result of that subexpression is not falsy (not `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `false`, `null`, or `undefined`) then the value of the `||` is whatever `arr[0]` is.  Otherwise, the value of the `||` is `'f'`. Only then will the `==` comparison be made, and `str` will be compared to *only one* of `arr[0]` and `'f'`.

Comment: Same for the first and second tests. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
var test = (str === 'foo' || str === 'bar');
```

You don't need to use `? :`, the equality already returns `true` or `false`.